# Google Map v3 - Center a infowindow when opened

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, center, infowindow

I have a Google Map that works fine but I just need to tweak it so that when a marker is clicked and opens up a info window, I'd like that marker (and the map) to center on the screen. This is so that the info window is the direct focus.

If it helps, I'm using [Infobox.js](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html) to create the infowindows. I've tried using Offset

> pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-97, -20)

but this doesn't center the infowindow or the map when you open the marker and its not accurate.

My code ([live example](http://visualartscambridge.org/home/)):

```js
var ib = new InfoBox();

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.204872, 0.120163),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        styles: styles,
        scrollwheel: false
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function () { ib.close() });

    setMarkers(map, sites);
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "loading..."
    });
}

var sites = [
    ['The Frontroom', 52.202977, 0.138938, 1, '<p>The Frontroom <br/>23-25 Gwydir Street, Cambridge, CB1 2LG <br/>01223 305 600 <br/> <a href="http://www.frontroomcambridge.com/">Website</a></p>'],
    ['Fitzwilliam Museum', 52.199678, 0.119931, 2, '<p>Fitzwilliam Museum <br/>Trumpington St, Cambridge, CB2 1RB <br/>01223 332900 <br/> <a href="http://www.fitzmuseum.cam.ac.uk/">Website</a></p>'],
    ['Wysing Arts centre', 52.182077, -0.06977, 3, '<p>Wysing Arts Centre <br/>Fox Rd, Cambridge <br/>CB23 2TX <br/>01954 718881 <br/> <a href="http://www.wysingartscentre.org/">Website</a></p>']
];

function createMarker(site, map) {
    var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(site[1], site[2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: siteLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: site[0],
        zIndex: site[3],
        html: site[4],
        icon: "http://visualartscambridge.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/map-dot.png"
    });

    var boxText = document.createElement("div");
    boxText.style.cssText = "margin-top: -200px; height:200px; background: white; padding: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 6px; -moz-border-radius: 6px; border-radius: 6px;";
    boxText.innerHTML = marker.html;

    var myOptions = {
        content: boxText,
        disableAutoPan: false,
        maxWidth: 0,
        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-97, -20),
        zIndex: null,
        boxStyle: {
            background: "url('http://visualartscambridge.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/box-marker.png') no-repeat",
            width: "195px"
        },
        closeBoxMargin: "-185px 12px 200px 2px",
        closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif",
        infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(0, 250),
        isHidden: false,
        alignBottom: true,
        pane: "floatPane",
        enableEventPropagation: false
    };

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
        ib.close();
        ib.setOptions(myOptions);
        ib.open(map, this);
    });
    return marker;
}

function setMarkers(map, markers) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        createMarker(markers[i], map);
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add a call to google.maps.Map.setCenter in the marker click listener.  This will center the map on the marker:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
 ib.close();
 ib.setOptions(myOptions);
 ib.open(map, this);
 map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
});
```

The above code will instantly jump to the new location, if you want a smoother animation, you can use `map.panTo(this.getPosition());` rather than `map.setCenter(this.getPosition());`