# When infowindow open, The infowindow slightly move left side in mobile view or mobile app in google map api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework, maps, google-maps-markers

Infowindow opens when we click on marker, but window slightly move left side and left property have 0 value in mobile view. How to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

An [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#introduction) displays content (usually text or images) in a popup window above the map, at a given location. The info window has a content area and a tapered stem. The tip of the stem is attached to a specified location on the map.

So usually infoWindow display above the marker. One solution is to set your desire position of infoWindow in your Map. Check this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#add) for more information.

Another solution is to try to place your marker(which have an infoWndow) in the middle of the screen when it is clicked, so that the infoWindow will display on the center of the screen.

Check this SO question [15946303](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946303/google-map-v3-center-a-infowindow-when-opened) and [18304525](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304525/center-google-maps-infowindow-on-load) on how to do that.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Please check this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple with mobile view. You see when you click on map it move left side slightly. which is not perfect. please give solution about it.                    https://drive.google.com/a/india.biztechconsultancy.com/file/d/0B6NjV5alVT5UT0tqVmJ5NXU4MzQ/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem but nobody seems to take care of it.
It's a Google Maps issue, fur sure. The problem rises up on Mobile App only, while is not present on the default desktop map.